# Ensure that AMQP exchange binding exists before publishing

Tags: rabbitmq, php-amqplib

**The System Layout**

We have three systems:

1. An API Endpoint (Publisher and Consumer)
2. The RabbitMQ Server
3. The main application/processor (Publisher and consumer)

System 1 and 3 both use Laravel, and use PHPAMQPLIB for interaction with RabbitMQ.

**The path of a message**

System 1 (the API Endpoint) sends a serialized job to the RabbitMQ Server for System 3 to process. It then immediately declares a new randomly named queue, binds an exchange to that queue with a correlation ID - and starts to listen for messages.

Meanwhile, system 3 finishes the job, and once it does, responds back with details from that job to RabbitMQ, on the exchange, with the correlation ID.

**The issue and what I've tried**

I often find that this process fails. The job gets sent and received, and the response gets sent - but system 1 never reads this response, and I don't see it published in RabbitMQ.

I've done some extensive debugging of this without getting to a root cause. My current theory is that System 3 is so quick at returning a response, that the new queue and exchange binding hasn't even been declared yet from System 1. This means the response from System 3 has nowhere to go, and as a result vanishes. This theory is mainly based on the fact that if I set jobs to be processed at a lower frequency on System 3, the system becomes more reliable. The faster the jobs process, the more unreliable it becomes.

The question is: How can I prevent that? Or is there something else that I'm missing? I of course want these jobs to process quickly and efficiently without breaking the Request/Response-pattern.

I've logged output from both systems - both are working with the same correlation ID's, and System 3 gets an ACK upon publishing - whilst System 1 has a declared queue with no messages that eventually just times out.

**Code Example 1: Publishing a Message**

```php
/**
 * Helper method to publish a message to RabbitMQ
 *
 * @param $exchange
 * @param $message
 * @param $correlation_id
 * @return bool
 */
public static function publishAMQPRouteMessage($exchange, $message, $correlation_id)
{
    try {
        $connection = new AMQPStreamConnection(
            env('RABBITMQ_HOST'),
            env('RABBITMQ_PORT'),
            env('RABBITMQ_LOGIN'),
            env('RABBITMQ_PASSWORD'),
            env('RABBITMQ_VHOST')
        );
        $channel = $connection->channel();

        $channel->set_ack_handler(function (AMQPMessage $message) {
            Log::info('[AMQPLib::publishAMQPRouteMessage()] - Message ACK');
        });

        $channel->set_nack_handler(function (AMQPMessage $message) {
            Log::error('[AMQPLib::publishAMQPRouteMessage()] - Message NACK');
        });

        $channel->confirm_select();

        $channel->exchange_declare(
            $exchange,
            'direct',
            false,
            false,
            false
        );

        $msg = new AMQPMessage($message);
        $channel->basic_publish($msg, $exchange, $correlation_id);

        $channel->wait_for_pending_acks();

        $channel->close();
        $connection->close();

        return true;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Code Example 2: Waiting for a Message Response**

```php
/**
 * Helper method to fetch messages from RabbitMQ.
 *
 * @param $exchange
 * @param $correlation_id
 * @return mixed
 */
public static function readAMQPRouteMessage($exchange, $correlation_id)
{
    $connection = new AMQPStreamConnection(
        env('RABBITMQ_HOST'),
        env('RABBITMQ_PORT'),
        env('RABBITMQ_LOGIN'),
        env('RABBITMQ_PASSWORD'),
        env('RABBITMQ_VHOST')
    );
    $channel = $connection->channel();

    $channel->exchange_declare(
        $exchange,
        'direct',
        false,
        false,
        false
    );

    list($queue_name, ,) = $channel->queue_declare(
        '',
        false,
        false,
        true,
        false
    );

    $channel->queue_bind($queue_name, $exchange, $correlation_id);

    $callback = function ($msg) {
        return self::$rfcResponse = $msg->body;
    };

    $channel->basic_consume(
        $queue_name,
        '',
        false,
        true,
        false,
        false,
        $callback
    );

    if (!count($channel->callbacks)) {
        Log::error('[AMQPLib::readAMQPRouteMessage()] - No callbacks registered!');
    }

    while (self::$rfcResponse === null && count($channel->callbacks)) {
        $channel->wait();
    }

    $channel->close();
    $connection->close();

    return self::$rfcResponse;
}
```

Grateful for any advise you can offer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be missing something, but when I read this:

> System 1 (the API Endpoint) sends a serialized job to the RabbitMQ Server for System 3 to process. It then immediately declares a new randomly named queue, binds an exchange to that queue with a correlation ID - and starts to listen for messages.

My first thought was "why do you wait until the message is sent before declaring the return queue?"

In fact, we have a whole series of separate steps here:

1. Generating a correlation ID
2. Publishing a message containing that ID to an exchange for processing elsewhere
3. Declaring a new queue to receive responses
4. Binding the queue to an exchange using the correlation ID
5. Binding a callback to the new queue
6. Waiting for responses

The response cannot come until after step 2, so we want to do that as late as possible. The only step that can't come before that is step 6, but it's probably convenient to keep steps 5 and 6 close together in the code. So I would rearrange the code to:

1. Generating a correlation ID
2. Declaring a new queue to receive responses
3. Binding the queue to an exchange using the correlation ID
4. Publishing a message containing the correlation ID to an exchange for processing elsewhere
5. Binding a callback to the new queue
6. Waiting for responses

This way, however quickly the response is published, it will be picked up by the queue declared in step 2, and as soon as you bind a callback and start waiting, you will process it.

Note that there is nothing that `readAMQPRouteMessage` knows that `publishAMQPRouteMessage` doesn't, so you can freely move code between them. All you need when you want to consume from the response queue is its name, which you can either save into a variable and pass around, or generate yourself rather than letting RabbitMQ name it. For instant, you could name it after the correlation ID it is listening for, so that you can always work out what it is with simple string manipulation, e.g. `"job_response.{$correlation_id}"`

Comment: The main cause is because I use RabbitMQ as a Queue Driver as well. In short, a job is queued and System 3 processes that, and then (in its job) sends the response data.

The correlation ID is as such just the ID of the job itself after it was dispatched.
Setting System 1 to declare and read can't be done before the publishing, because the Job hasn't been dispatched (and as a result, the Job ID doesn't exist) - and because reading consumes that thread until a response is received or it times out.

Does that make sense, or am I still thinking about it wrong?

Comment: @CmdrSharp System 1 decides on the ID, and tells System 3, so logically it must be chosen at some point before the message is published to RabbitMQ. In fact, your code listing shows that the `publishAMQPRouteMessage` function has the `$correlation_id` passed into it. The response queue can be declared and bound as soon as you have decided what that ID is. You can then leave the queue declared for as long as you like before consuming from it, that's why it's a queue.

Comment: Sure - but you're missing that the correlation ID is the actual ID of the job it processes. The message it returns has no correlation to the job - but the job ID is something that both System 1 and 3 have access to. An alternative would be to NOT use the Job ID as the correlation, and instead include some form of arbitrarily generated correlation ID with the other job data. That would allow for what you propose - perhaps that's the way to go about it. I'll give it some thought!

Comment: @CmdrSharp I don't see the problem. In the `publishAMQPRouteMessage` function, or just before it, you have all the information you need to declare and bind the queue. There is nothing that `readAMQPRouteMessage` knows that `publishAMQPRouteMessage` doesn't. All you need to later consume from that queue is its name, which you can either pass around, or generate yourself rather than letting RabbitMQ name it, so that you can always work out what it is from the ID, e.g. `"job_response.{$correlation_id}"`

Comment: That is correct - but publishing using the methods included in the question happens only on System 3 (the processor). The job itself is published first (though using a different library to interact with Laravels queue system) - and only after it is, do I have the correlation ID. This means the job is available for System 3, whilst System 1 might not have had time to declare and bind a queue yet. Remember it can't bind the exchange without the correlation ID, and it only has that correlation ID after the job is already made available.

Comment: This is why I believe I will have to alter the system to not use the jobs generated ID as the correlation ID - but instead make something else that is passed along with the job when it is initially processed. That way I can declare the queue earlier (as System 1 will know the correlation ID before it sends the job away) - and can as such declare and bind before dispatching, and finally listening. Does that make sense?

Comment: @CmdrSharp OK, I had assumed that the code listings were both from System 1 (the "publisher" in RabbitMQ terminology), but I see now that you hadn't actually specified that. At some point, though there is definitely code on System 1 that knows that ID, *before* sending it to the RabbitMQ server. I think what you're saying is that that happens in library code which you don't want to modify. In that case, yes, just use some other identifier that's generated outside that library code.

Comment: The difference in our understanding is that I was thinking only in terms of when the message was sent over the network, but I think you are considering it "dispatched" or "sent off" as soon as it enters the Laravel library code which you don't want to change.

Comment: I understand better what you mean now. I took some time to rewrite the current implementation to use an arbitrary UUID for its routing key instead of the job ID (which isn't returned anywhere from Laravel's source until dispatch), and as you anticipated, this works a whole lot better! I can see a clear delay between when the application declares and binds now, and to when it actually dispatches (step 4 of your revised plan) that was never there before.

Thank you very much for your input and persistence! :)